# Wi-Fi solution for network storage?

Tags: bluetooth, wifi, storage, network

We are in the process of developing network storage with integrated Wi-Fi. Here we are facing problem. We have checked various solutions from Texas instruments and Microchip. But CC3000 from Texas instrument only supports speed of upto 11 MBPS and it doesnt support the N standard. Similar story with microchip module. If anyone has experience with high speed Wi-Fi module.do share your experience. Any solution has Wi-Fi + Bluetooth combination will be added advantage.

Comment: Broadcom: http://www.broadcom.com/products/Wireless-LAN/802.11-Wireless-LAN-Solutions

Comment: @Kaz great solutions.What about the devkits ? Do broadcom provides any because I couldnt find one.

Comment: Broadcom will make you sign an NDA and make you promise to buy a bajillion units before dealing with you.

Comment: Marvell is a Broadcom competitor which offers pretty much the same portfolio. One potential advantage is I found that their SoCs tend to be ARM based and a little more open than Broadcom (even though you'll still probably have to sign a NDA). But I know datasheets for some older Marvell devices are readily found on the internet. Alternatively, you can just go with Broadcom and reverse engineer DD-WRT or some other router firmware...

Comment: Broadcom and Marvell are very geared towards large customers with large quantities. TI is, from my experience, very friendly to smaller customers. NDAs might be required but you can build a complete system from all their off the shelf design and dev kits.

Comment: If your system can push 10+ Mbps, you're probably running linux of some sort. Have you considered just using a USB-WiFi module internally? That may be considerably easier then trying to get any big company to look into selling you parts in small-volume. You just need a MCU that supports USB host (you probably have this), and to compile the proper linux WiFi kernel drivers.

Answer (score 2):

Texas Instruments provides other solutions for high speed WiFi. WiFi solutions is really divided into two main camps:

1) The fully integrated solution such as CC3000 that offloads microcontroller but can achieve typically 5Mbps

2) The WiFi chipset where you need to provide a processor and connect it to a WiFi chipset, connects to a high speed processor and can achieve tens of Mbps.

Seems you need #2 because solution #1 is limited. TI has the WiLink8 which can achieve 60Mbps+, but you will need a processor such as their AM335x to run linux to use it. This is the same case as Broadcom, Marvell, etc. However, TI provides a lot of public information and ready made kits that have WiFi running out of the box.

TI's WiFi also has Bluetooth enabled in the Linux and in the chipset itself.

Take a look at TI's [Getting Started for WiLink 8](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/WL18xx_First_Time_Getting_Started_Guide)

BTW, if you are a company developing a product, I highly recommend contacting TI's sales. They can help you find the right solution.